# svelte update with no change always triggers re-render

Tags: svelte

I've been playing a bit with svelte but I have a hard time managing renders.

I noticed that whenever a store's `update` method is called a rerender is triggered, even if the store didn't change. I figured that I might be doing something wrong but I'm not sure what it is.

Here's a simple example. I was expecting that clicking on the button would not display anything in the console since there's no actual change (like Redux for instance), but I get a new message every time.

**App.svelte:**

```html
{#each $store as value}
    {value}
{/each}
<button on:click={updateStore} type="button">Click me</button>

<script>
    import { afterUpdate } from 'svelte'
    import { store, updateStore } from './store.js'
    
    afterUpdate(() => console.log('render'))
</script>
```

**store.js:**

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const store = writable([])

export const updateStore = () => store.update(s => s)
```

Is it an issue? Am I supposed to have those messages in my console or should I add something like a `get(store)` to decide if I want to actually call `update`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code Svelte generates knows nothing about the value of the store and if it changed or not, it will render everytime a store update happens. To achieve what you want, you would have to wrap `writable` with your own implementation which checks if the object reference changed and depending on that emit an event or not. Rough implementation:

```js
export function customWritable (value, start) {
   const _writable = writable(value, start);
   const set = (newVal) => {
     if (newVal !== value) {
       value = newVal;
       _writable.set(newVal);
     }
   };
   const update = (updateFn) => {
      set(updateFn(value));
   };
   
   return { set, update, subscribe: _writable.subscribe };
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed explanation!